# "mapper [geo.coordinates] of different type, current_type [geo_point], merged_type [ObjectMapper]

Tags: kibana

Trying to load sample data from Kibana using the tutorial : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-load-dataset.html but facing en error of "error" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "mapper [geo.coordinates] of different type, current_type [geo_point], merged_type [ObjectMapper]"

curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST "https://Kibana_username:Kibana_password@cd90859873ee41f2ba44736569855ac6.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary @logs.jsonl

{
      "index" : {
        "_index" : "logstash-2015.05.20",
        "_type" : "log",
        "_id" : "VLO5SWsB2ropsYqSYd-A",
        "status" : 400,
        "error" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "mapper [geo.coordinates] of different type, current_type [geo_point], merged_type [ObjectMapper]"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 3):

The error that you are getting is because, in your version of `logs.json`, the content looks like this: `{"index":{"_index":"logstash-2015.05.18","_type":"log"}}` but if you read the documentation:

> Indices created in Elasticsearch 6.0.0 or later may only contain a single mapping type. Indices created in 5.x with multiple mapping types will continue to function as before in Elasticsearch 6.x. Types will be deprecated in APIs in Elasticsearch 7.0.0, and completely removed in 8.0.0.

So if you change the file content like this: `{"index":{"_index":"logstash-2015.05.18"}}`, it would work properly.
But in the latest update of this source file, this error is fixed.